# Expect to receive working for any_instance but not for specific one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following rspec:

```
context 'when there is an incoming error' do
      it 'should update status of url to error' do 
        url = create(:url)
        error_params = {error: 'whatever', url_id : url.id}

        expect(url).to receive(:set_error)
        post :results, error_params
      end
end
```

And the results action looks like this:

```
def results
  url = Url.find(url_id: params['url_id'])
  if params.key?('error') && !params['error'].blank?
      url.set_error
  end
end
```

If I do it like this, the test does not pass:

```
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

However, if I change to:

`expect_any_instance_of(Url).to receive(:set_error)`.

It passes. I just have one Url, so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: What does `set_error` do? Suppose you have a corresponding method `error?` to get the error info back out, then you can change the url variable to an ivar (`@url`) and just `expect(assigns(:url)).to be_error`. This way you do not need stubs, your are just testing the publicly visible effects of your method.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `to receive` expectation, it is connected to a specific Ruby object.

When the `results` action is called, it instantiates a *new* `url` object. It represents the same database object that you called your expectation on in the Rspec example. But *it isn't the same Ruby object* - it's a new object with (probably) the same data. So the expectation fails.

To illustrate:

```
describe ".to_receive" do
  it "works on Ruby objects" do
    url = Url.create(:url)
    same_url = Url.find(url.id)
    expect(url).to_not receive(:to_s)
    same_url.to_s
  end
end
```

To (somewhat) get the desired behaviour you could use `any_instance` and change the controller so that it assigns the url object to an instance variable. In that way you can inspect the url object easier:

```
# Change your action so that it saves the url object as an instance variable
def results
  @url = Url.find(url_id: params['url_id'])
  if params[:error].present?
    @url.set_error
  end
end

# Change your spec to look at the assigned variable
context 'when there is an incoming error' do
  it 'should update status of url to error' do 
    url = create(:url)
    error_params = {error: 'whatever', url_id: url.id}
    expect_any_instance_of(Url).to receive(:set_error)
    post :results, error_params
    expect(assigns(:url)).to eq(url)
  end
end
```

Since `assigns` only lets you inspect the assigned ivar *after* the controller action has been executed, you can't use it to create a receive expectation.

Comment: Really interesting. So what is the solution for these cases?

Comment: I added a way to get similar results.